# TFS Labels, confused by the Changeset column

Tags: tfs

I use Labels in TFS so as to keep track of my deliveries. The Build service also labels each build, which is OK

However, in the Labels window (History / Labels), the column named 'ChangeSet' has a weird content, with always the same number displayed (which is the very first Changeset number of the codebase, by the way), regardless of the Changeset chosen while creating the label.

Do anyone have the same behaviour? Any hints on why this particular Changeset number is displayed?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That column shows the version of the files and folders at the time they were for the changeset selected. So for a folder, its the changeset of the folder itself, and not anything within the folder.

It can be a bit confusing, but if you are labeling at a high directory level in source, it's likely that the container the label was applied to hasn't been changed since the first changeset.  So you will always see that first changeset number.

If you open that label and drill down to where the changed files are, you will see the changeset numbers are your more recent changesets.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, I always think the SVN way, with global version number

Comment: It makes sense, the explanation, but not the outcome.

Comment: so you can find out which changeset was really labeled using the commandline `tf history . /stopafter:1 /noprompt /r /version:L"<my label>" ` , which will show you the changeset, that way you don't have to hunt down which file changed for that changeset to verify the label was attached to the correct changeset.  Note, if you drop that /r, it will show you the very same behavior you are asking about.